# High traffic management in WP

Tags: performance, optimization, server-load

I have to develop a site in Wordpress similar to an already existing site in JSP which handles approx.`50K users a day and 200 users` at a time. And in load testing i get that wordpress can handle only `40 users` at a time (with `Super Cache` plugin `ON`).
Also I have hosted my site on a `Shared hosted server`.

So please suggest me some way or guide me to `optimize` my wordpress site so that it can also handle the same traffic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shared hosting? Get a VPS! Even a coin will feel heavy on a paper boat :)

Comment: Ya i will sure go for it. But are you sure that's the only thing to do ? Will it make this much difference 40 -> 200 + users?

Comment: As your hoster if this is the limit first.

Comment: Ya it is a shared hosted server issue...Thanks you all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce the amount of plugins. Check your theme for memory intense stuff or lots of queries.

Add this line to your footer or hook it to the `shutdown` hook to see some basic information:

```
<!-- Time needed to print this page: <?php timer_stop( 0, 3 ); ?> Number of queries needed to process this request: <?php get_num_queries(); ?> -->
```

Then take a look at your site through source code and at the bottom you'll find the html comment containing this basic data. Then start disabling single plugins to see the difference and their impact on performance.

Furthermore I'd say the max user restriction is not by wp, but by your shared hosting account.

Comment: after inserting your code i get this result...Time needed to print this page: 0.280 Number of queries needed to process this request: 73

Comment: also i jst have WPML plugin installed in my site !!

Comment: 73 is pretty high. As I wrote: Start deactivating each and meassure the difference.

Comment: I deactiveted WPML and it becomes 29... But i think that is not the solution.

Comment: WPML (imho) is crap. The user restriction still seems to be a server/hosting issue. Drop them a mail and then come back here with their answer.

Comment: @kaiser..Thanks man.. I got reply from than and they said their server only supports 35 concurrent users..They suggest me to go for VPs or dedicated server.. !!